# Why can't I use a &str in trim_matches() like in trim_right_matches()?

Tags: string, rust, pattern-matching

In `trim_right_matches` I can pass a string value:

```
println!("{}", "[(foo)]".trim_right_matches(")]"));
// [(foo
```

I cannot, however, use a string value in `trim_matches`:

```
println!("{}", "[(foo)]".trim_matches("[()]"));
```

Because I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>: std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not satisfied
 --> test.rs:2:27
  |
2 |     println!("{}", "[(foo)]".trim_matches("[()]"));
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not implemented for `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

The following code works:

```
println!("{}", "[(foo)]".trim_matches(&['(', '[', ']', ')'] as &[_]));
// foo
```

However, it is long and not as easy to read as a single string value; I want to be able to use a string value like with `trim_right_matches`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first bit of code doesn't do what you think. It trims exactly the string `")]"` from the end, but it would not modify the string `"([foo])"`. In other words, passing a string to the trim functions means "trim exactly this string", not "trim all of the characters occurring in this string". The code that doesn't compile wouldn't do what you want, because it would only trim away the exact string `"[()]"`, and this doesn't occur in your examples.

Passing an array of chars instead trims all of the characters individually, no matter what order.

So you want the array of chars, even though passing a string looks so much more convenient.

As for why the code you wrote doesn't compile, ljedrz answered that part.

Comment: I thought that `trim_matches` in rust was same as `trim` in PHP.

Comment: Not quite. And unfortunately the documentation for this is not ideal.

Answer (score 8):

These two functions have similar signatures, but if you look closer you'll notice that their search patterns are actually different:

`trim_right_matches`:

```
pub fn trim_right_matches<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> &'a str
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: ReverseSearcher<'a> // ReverseSearcher
```

`trim_matches`:

```
pub fn trim_matches<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> &'a str
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: DoubleEndedSearcher<'a> // DoubleEndedSearcher
```

In [the docs for `DoubleEndedSearcher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/pattern/trait.DoubleEndedSearcher.html#examples) you can find the explanation why `&str` can't be a `DoubleEndedSearcher`:

> `(&str)::Searcher` is not a `DoubleEndedSearcher` because the pattern `"aa"`
>   in the haystack `"aaa"` matches as either `"[aa]a"` or `"a[aa]"`, depending
>   from which side it is searched.

As for why your workaround works:

```
"[(foo)]".trim_matches(&['(', '[', ']', ')'] as &[_]));
```

It's because it is actually not matching on a `&str`, but on `&[char]`, which is not a string slice but a slice of an array of characters, which is a valid `DoubleEndedSearcher`.